# Как показать содержимое строки из другого класса в TextView?

Tags: java, android, строки, textview

Здравствуйте, в классе есть код:

```
...
final String test = response.headers().get("example");
Log.d(TAG, "example=%s", test);

...
```

Как можно показать (передать) в активити в **TextView**, содержимое этой строки **test** (В логах показывается нужная информация из строки test. Нужно как то перенести её в активити , и там показать во вьюшке)

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы активити видело какую-то переменную другого класса? Сделайте в классе вашего activity `public static String test`, а из вашего класса, в котором есть ваш код, установите ее значение: `YourActivity.test = test`. Это будет работать, но с точки зрения ооп данное решение является в целом костылем, ибо приложение должно быть спроектировано так, чтобы объекты между собой общались вызовами функций.

Comment: Не слушайте вредных советов, не делайте `static` переменных.

Comment: В класс, который отправляет http запрос прокидывайте ссылку на `Activity`. Если это `AsyncTask`, то в `onPostExecute` вызывайте потом метод прокинутой `Activity`.

Comment: Ну и как прокинуть ссылку на активити? и потом вызвать?

Comment: Сделал как написал @selya, и вроде всё работает., только не пойму, чем плох этот метод? У меня в одном месте только используется данная строка и 1 раз.

Comment: @Suvitruf я сделал оговорку, что это возможное, но не лучшее решение

Comment: Тогда раз это возможное решение , а не "плохое", давайте подтвердим ваш вариант ответом! Большое спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Антон добавил в виде ответа

Comment: @Антон предложенное вам решение, не плохое, а ужасное. Очень надеюсь, что вы не будете так делать в реальном приложении, а узнаете что то про колбэки. В вопросе же не хватает контекста. Что это за класс, в котором есть код, от чего наследуется? экземпляр этого класса вызывает активити, в которой надо показать текст? это запрос какой то в рантайме? Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы был минимальный воспроизводимый пример, тогда ваша проблема может быть решена гораздо лучшим способом

Comment: @pavlofff, это класс IcyDataSource implements HttpDataSource . Метадату беру с сервера. Нужно просто напросто одну строку в TextView вывести и всё. На макете разметки создал textview , присобачил статическую переменную., только не пойму, чем это ужасно? У меня приложение может крашиться? нагрузка колоссальная, или что? Если будет необходимость еще чтото вывести из класса какого-нибудь, то я обязательно попробую сделать это другим образом, раз этот вариант "ужасный", и вам не нравится))

Comment: дело в том, что он не лично мне не нравится, а это неприемлемо в android-разработке, так как вы работаете с компонентом жизненного цикла системы, а не пользовательским классом. Ваш класс наследуется от каких то классов API или он пользовательский?

Comment: Какой именно класс? тот что public class IcyDataSource implements HttpDataSource ?

Comment: тот из которого вам нужно передать данные в активити

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно, чтобы ваш Activity имел доступ к какой-то переменной из другого класса, то можно создать статическое поле в вашем Activity:

```
public static String test;
```

И потом из любой части программы задайте значение этому полю:

```
MyActivity.test = test;
```

Хоть данное решение и является рабочим, однако если вам приходится прибегать к этому методу, то, вероятно, ваше приложение спроектировано плохо. Открытых (`public`) изменяемых (не `final`) полей следует в целом избегать.

Более правильное решение в теории выглядело бы так:

1. В классе `MyActivity` определяется статический метод `getInstance()`:

   ```
   ...

   public static MyActivity getInstance() {
       return ...
   }

   ....
   ```

   который возвращает экземпляр `MyActivity`, в который нужно что-либо передать.
2. В классе `MyActivity` также объявляется метод `setText(String)`:

   ```
   public void setText(String text) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   внутри которого вы делаете все необходимое с данным текстом
3. Далее передаете текст из любой части программы:

   ```
   MyActivity.getInstance().setText(text);
   ```

Этот вариант уже выглядит вполне неплохо

Comment: Единственное решение, которое в фреймворке Android выглядит неплохо - передача обновляемых в рантайме данных через колбэк (интерфейс обратного вызова). Что вы тут написали и то и другое - ересь.

Comment: @pavloff предложите свой ответ) формулировка вопроса была: "как можно?". Ответ я дал. Если бы вопрос стоял "как максимально правильно?", "как правильно спроектировать?", "как принято делать это коде android-приложения?", то ответ был бы другим, и, возможно, не моим, не ересью и так далее

Comment: но так нельзя. по крайней мере в android. То, что это работает еще не разрешает таких действий с компонентами жизненного цикла.

Comment: вы может ответите тогда, на что влияет использование статики ? приложение не падает? не лагает, не крашит, не зависает. задача выполнена получается? Но вы продолжаете говорить что это ересь. Так напишите чётко и правильно шаг за шагом правильный вариант. Или "эго" не позволяет?))

Comment: А когда человек уже начнёт писать, он постепенно будет находит ответы на другие свои вопросы, и тогда уже он сам будет понимать, когда так можно делать, когда - нет, и как следует это делать в данном случае. А вы просто говорите "нет, так делать нельзя. Почему? А так не принято. Делайте вот так...", что будет вызывать лишь непонимание

Comment: про колбэки здесь уже и без меня написано гораздо более, чем требуется. Отношение - "не падает, значит я молодец" до добра вас не доведет. Насчет "не лагает, не зависает" я бы не стал так смело утверждать, вы тестировали?

Comment: Не переживайте, с точки зрения исполнения нет никаких проблем (по крайней мере пока вы не пишете/читаете какую-то переменную одновременно из разных потоков). Проблема в том, как сконструирован android framework. Точнее в том, что большинство задач, которые требуется решить с его помощью, решаются с помощью колбэков. Это равносильно тому, что вы в храме вместо витражных стекол поставите окна пвх. Оно будет работать, но так не принято. Однако есть ситуации, когда так делать можно и нужно.

Comment: @selya, спасибо за информацию, приму к сведению )) .

Comment: про колбеки здесь и без меня написа.......У вас не лагает.. а вы тестирова...? Ну так дайте точный и полный ответ этому вопросу , зачем отвечать вопросами на вопросы?

Comment: @Антон Это не равносильно тому, что пластиковые окна и что то там еще ... ситуаций, в которых так можно и нужно делать с компонентами жизненного цикла нет и быть не может и проблема не только в многопоточности (это очевидно), а в том, что вы работаете с компонентом жизненного цикла и он не должен иметь никакой связанности со стороны пользовательских классов

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку активити - компонент жизненного цикла системы, для него не подходят "простые" способы взаимодействия между классами, так как активити не должна иметь связанности с классами, которые могут жить дольше, чем жизненный цикл самой активити.

Для передачи динамических данных, обновляемых в процессе выполнения, в активити традиционно используется колбэк (интерфейс обратного вызова). Пример такого колбэка:

Класс, который генерирует данные в процессе выполнения программы:

```
public class DataSource {

    StringCallback stringCallback;

    // Определяем интерфейс обратного вызова
   public interface StringCallback {
       public void onResult (String result);
   }

   // Метод для регистрации интерфейса на принимающей данные стороне
   public void setStringCallback (StringCallback callback){
       stringCallback = callback;
   }

   // некоторый метод получения данных
   public void getData(){

       // искуственная задержка в 10 сек., изображающяя время на получение данных
       try {
           Thread.sleep (10000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       // Получены данные в виде строки "Бинго"
       String data = "Bingo!";

       // Передаем полученные данные приемнику (в активити)
       stringCallback.onResult(data);
   }
}
```

Активити, в которой нужно получить данные из другого класса:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // виджет, куда выводить полученный текст
        text = findViewById(R.id.text);

        // регестрируем колбэк в активити
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setStringCallback(new DataSource.StringCallback() {

            //  получаем данные при их поступлении
            @Override
            public void onResult(String result) {
                // выводим полученные данные на экран
                text.setText(result);
            }
        });

        // некоторый метод запроса данных, которые нужно отобразить на экране
        ds.getData();
    }
}
```

Таким способом можно передать любые данные: примитивные типы, классы, коллекции и тп., так же и любое количество разных данных. То, что нужно передать определяется только сигнатурой метода интерфейса-колбэка (`onResult()` в нашем примере)

Это простейший, но вполне рабочий пример для несложного взаимодействия. Для более серьезной работы такого рода в последнее время принято использовать реактивное взаимодейсвие через *RxJava*, ранее использовались шины данных, как *EventBus*